# Member function template of nested class in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I was messing around with templates in MSVC 2019 and encountered the following situation:

```
template <class T>
class A {
    struct B;
}

template <>
struct A<int>::B {
    template <class U>
    void f(U u);    
}

template <class U>
void A<int>::B::f(U u) {

}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

which produces
the following compiler error:

> C2244 unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

My question is: can I have a class template with a nested struct, and then define this struct only for one specialization of that enclosing class such that the struct has a template member function?

---

Obs1: Firstly, I thought this was due to A templated with int not being instantiated yet, but adding an explicit instantiation of A with int template parameter does not help. 
Obs2: Defining f inline inside the class body does fix the problem, however I want to be able to specialize f.

---

English is not my primary language, forgive me for any mistakes I may have made.

Comment: The code successfully compiles in GCC if you add semicolons after each class definition.

Comment: No problem with [either GCC or Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/vPWrja). Have you defined them in the same source file?

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, the semicolons were a typo in my post. I think this is a bug with MSVC then... I did defined them in the same source file by the way